# How to enable nodmodeset with mkusb

Tags: nomodeset, mkusb

My bootable USB flash drive containing Ubuntu 18.04 was made with mkusb.
Although the system seems to boot when using this flash drive, I can't see anything.  In the past, when I encountered this with other installers, I always had to enable nomodeset first.
When I clicked on Try Ubuntu with persistence and clicked on e, I saw the following line:
linux  ($root)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
I edited this line to read:
linux  ($root)/casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash nomodeset
 How can I save this change temporarily so that it is possible to boot from the flash drive?

Comment: I'm trying to make a general answer, but I can give you more specific help if you tell me if you have a persistent live system or a live-only (cloned) system?

Comment: I have a persistent live Ubuntu 18.04 system on my USB flash drive

Comment: I suggest that you connect your persistent USB flash drive to a running computer with 'any' linux (live or installed) and edit the file `mountpoint/boot/grub/grub.cfg` according to the first case in the answer. Replace `mountpoint` with *your* actual mountpoint and I suggest that you use the following command line,  **`nano mountpoint/boot/grub/grub.cfg`**. This way `nomodeset` will persist until you remove it (editing in a similar way). Good luck :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Boot options in persistent live drive made my mkusb

You should edit the file

```
mountpoint/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

similar to what you do directly from the grub menu, that is modify the end of the line that starts with `linux`.

If you want to play safe, make a backup copy of `grub.cfg`

---

**Seen when the drive is connected to another [running] linux system**

```
sudo lsblk -o name,fstype,label,mountpoint /dev/sdc
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL                    MOUNTPOINT
sdc                                     
├─sdc1 ntfs    usbdata                  /media/sudodus/usbdata
├─sdc2                                  
├─sdc3 vfat    usbboot                  /media/sudodus/usbboot
├─sdc4 iso9660 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64 /media/sudodus/Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64
└─sdc5 ext4    casper-rw                /media/sudodus/casper-rw
```

This file resides in the third partition `usbboot`, in my case mounted at `/media/sudodus/usbboot`

**Seen when the persistent live system is running - continue past grub**

```
$ sudo lsblk -o name,fstype,label,mountpoint /dev/sdb
NAME   FSTYPE  LABEL                    MOUNTPOINT
sdb                                     
├─sdb1 ntfs    usbdata                  /media/ubuntu/usbdata
├─sdb2                                  
├─sdb3 vfat    usbboot                  /media/ubuntu/usbboot
├─sdb4 iso9660 Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS amd64 /cdrom
└─sdb5 ext4    casper-rw                /media/ubuntu/casper-rw
```

This file resides in the third partition `usbboot`, in this case mounted at `/media/ubuntu/usbboot` (where `ubuntu` is the default live username).

**So edit the file with a text editor; I use `nano`**

```
nano mountpoint/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

and you will see several linux lines that have `---` at the end. Edit all the lines that you intend to use like so

```
linux ... nomodeset ---
```

or generally with some other boot option

```
linux ... your-new-boot-option ---
```

where `...` represents everything currently between `linux` and `---` that you want to keep. For example, you keep it all or you may skip `quiet splash`. Please notice that there should be a space character before and after the new boot option.

**It is enough to save this file. There is no preprocessing in the persistent live system.**

### Boot options in a live-only drive make by mkusb

Boot options in a live-only drive make by mkusb must be added at the grub menu or syslinux menu and cannot be saved, because the system is **cloned** from the iso file and inherits the iso9660 file system, which is read-only.

**In grub** you get into editing mode by pressing the <kbd>e</kbd> key.

Edit the line starting with `linux` as described above.

You can [only] save this edit temporarily, with <kbd>F10</kbd> or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>x</kbd> for this particular boot instance.

**In syslinux** you use the <kbd>F6</kbd> option.

- Press the Escape key to get to the line
- Edit the line
- Press the Enter key to continue.

If you mark the menu item (press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to select), you can press the <kbd>Escape</kbd> key to continue (and the selection will be remembered, even if you cannot see it in the 'line'). Press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to continue.

### See more about boot options at the following link and links from it,

[Boot options](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808)

Comment: In my case, I solved the problem by changing the line: linux   ($root)/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash persistent ---   to: linux   ($root)/casper/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash persistent --- nomodeset ---       and the clicked on F10

Comment: @VolkerBradley, Congratulations, and thanks for sharing your solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

I had success saving a copy and then editing the menu entries in
/usr/share/mkusb/grub.cfg before running the tool.  In my case I used
upefi mode to create a USB bootable either via BIOS or UEFI.

I also removed all but the first item and renamed the item, so it looks
like there is only one boot option on the USB and it has a branded name.

We use this mechanism to build support USBs to send to our customers.

I did realize if you rename an entry, you should keep the string "ubuntu.iso "
at the front of the entry since that string is used as a key in dus-persistent multiple times around lines 1326-1329
(or else I guess you could patch that script also, did not try).

...
-e '/menuentry "ubuntu/a \ set root=(hd0,4)' 
-e '/menuentry "memtest/a \  set root=(hd0,3)' 
-e '/loopback/d' -e 's#iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu.iso ##' 
-e 's/loop/$root/' 
-e "s%ubuntu.iso%$menuname%g"
...